# How to get updated fields name & their value from trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, dynamic-sql

i could figure out how to get updated fields name from trigger. say i have customer table if customer name and location name has been updated then we can have get those fields name issuing the below statement from trigger like

```
DECLARE @idTable INT
SELECT @idTable = T.id FROM sysobjects P JOIN sysobjects T ON P.parent_obj = T.id WHERE P.id = @@procid
DECLARE @Columns_Updated VARCHAR(50)

SELECT  @Columns_Updated = ISNULL(@Columns_Updated + ', ', '') + name 
FROM    syscolumns 
WHERE   id = @idTable   
AND     CONVERT(VARBINARY,REVERSE(COLUMNS_UPDATED())) & POWER(CONVERT(BIGINT, 2), colorder - 1)  > 0
```

but i want the new value too for those fields name because i want to generate a update statement in string variable like

```
SET @SQL="update customer set cutsname='ALFKI',locname='kolkata' where id=10"
```

i can get cutsname & locname from the above sql but i do not know how to get values for those fields.

main concern is how to know the value and how to construct the update statement in string variable with name & value.

it will be great help if anyone share this idea. thanks

### update

very easily we can generate select statement from trigger like this way

```
SET @SQL='SELECT '+@Columns_Updated+' FROM MYTable'
```

i guess there must be some trick exist to generate update statement with updated columns name with value from trigger.if u have any idea then plzz share with me. thanks

Comment: why do you want to do this anyway? is it only because you want to update same columns and with same values in `Customer` table ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you need to use the [SET CONTEXT_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) command.

you can associate up to 128 bytes of data with the current connection using the SET CONTEXT_INFO command.

Now what you can do is generate one **UNIQUEIDENTIFIER** and set it in the context like so.

```
DECLARE @newId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, @Ctx VARBINARY(128)
SET @newId = newid()

SELECT @Ctx = CONVERT(VARBINARY(128), @newId)
SET CONTEXT_INFO @Ctx
```

Now in your trigger retrieve the value of this context like so -

```
DECLARE @CtxData varchar(128)
SELECT @CtxData = CONVERT(VarChar(128), CONTEXT_INFO())
```

and track the updated column and its new value into one new table (or temp table) in your trigger like so -

```
IF UPDATE(cutsname)
BEGIN
    SET @colName = 'cutsname'

    SELECT @colVal = cutsname
    FROM inserted
END

INSERT INTO newTable (
    ColName
    ,ColValue
    ,NewUniqueId
    )
VALUES (
    @colName
    ,@colVal
    ,@CtxData
    )
```

and same way for other column.

Now access this table outside of trigger let say in your SP as below and track in your audit table.

```
SELECT *
FROM newTable
WHERE NewUniqueId = @newId -- this @newId is the id which we set in CONTEXT_INFO
```

That's it. Well you can redefine this logic as per your requirement if you find it too lengthy.

### EDITED

Okay here i have redefined the insert query by combining `INSERTED` and `DELETED` virtual table.

```
INSERT INTO newTable (
    ColName
    ,ColValue
    ,NewUniqueId
    )
SELECT CASE -- to track column name
        WHEN I.cutsname <> D.cutsname
            THEN 'cutsname'
        ELSE ''
        END
    ,CASE -- to track updated new value
        WHEN I.cutsname <> D.cutsname
            THEN I.cutsname
        ELSE ''
        END
    ,@CtxData

UNION ALL

    CASE 
        WHEN I.locname <> D.locname
            THEN 'locname'
        ELSE ''
        END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN I.locname <> D.locname
            THEN I.locname
        ELSE ''
        END
    ,@CtxData

UNION ALL

    CASE 
        WHEN I.OtherColumn <> D.OtherColumn
            THEN 'OtherColumn'
        ELSE ''
        END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN I.OtherColumn <> D.OtherColumn
            THEN I.OtherColumn
        ELSE ''
        END
    ,@CtxData
FROM INSERTED I
JOIN DELETED D ON I.id = D.id
```

So now no needs to use `IF UPDATE(colName)` for each column... Thanks to Aaron Bertrand for pointing out regarding this if Update() in comment.

================================================================================
Apart from above solution you can use [**Change Data Capture**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510744%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) feature in sql server 2008.

There is a superb article available at [**this link.**](http://simpleverse.wordpress.com/2009/06/24/sql-2008-change-data-capture-the-basics/) At least just go through it.

Comment: You know that `IF UPDATE()` just tells you if that column was referenced, it doesn't actually mean that the value has changed, right?

Comment: thanks for reply. there is problem the way u shown to generate update statement because if too many columns has been updated then i would need to construct many if statement. i need some short cut way. thanks